# Обновление данных в разных компонентах из сервиса

Tags: angular5

Есть 2 компонента А и Б , а так же сервис с двумя функциями   "получить данные" и "обновить данные" в бд.
Модель данных, используется в обоих компонентах, сервис зарегистрирован в  общем модуле.
Как сделать получение обновленной модели в обоих компонентах после обновления данных в б.д. ?
т.е. как заставить отработать функцию получить данные ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создайте генератор событий в том же сервисе, который будет генерировать событие для двух подписчиков:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
class Service {
    public dataUpdated$ = new Subject();

    public getData() {
        return this.http.get(URL);
    }

    public updateData(body) {
        return this.http.patch(URL, body);
    }
}
```

Далее делаем подписку в обоих компонентах:

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';

class AComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(service: Service) {
        service.dataUpdated$.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('Новый объект: ', data);
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}

class BComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(service: Service) {
        service.dataUpdated$.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('Новый объект: ', data);
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Вы так же должны знать что изменилось, я надеюсь, что ваше АПИ возвращает измененную модель:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';

public updateData(body) {
    return this.http.patch(URL, body).pipe(
        tap((data) => this.dataUpdated$.next(data))
    );
}
```

Если же нет - то вы вручную мутируете объект и так же через `tap` генерируете событие.

Comment: спасибо, понятно с какой стороны подступится  далее будем копать